# Understanding "order under cyclic permutation"

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

[Paragraph in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSZjF.png)

Hello,

I was wondering what it means for a sequence of zeros and ones to have an order under cyclic permutation. I understand what a cyclic permutation is; however, I do not understand what it means for a cyclic permutation to have an order.

For example, take a sequence of zeros and ones of length 5 containing three ones: 1,0,1,1,0.

How do I know what its order under cyclic permutation is?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I find it a bit confusing to use set notation for sequences.

Comment: changed the format- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the order under cyclic permutation refers to the least natural number $n$ such that cyclically permuting the sequence $n$ times results in the sequence itself. In your example this is $5$, the length of the sequence, but generally it can be any divisor of the length of the sequence. For instance, the sequence $1,1,0,1,1,0$ has order $3$ under cyclic permutation.

Comment: Per wikipedia, a permutation is cyclic i.f.f. it consists of a single nontrivial cycle. However, there are many single nontrivial cycles, right? So is the order the least natural number n s.t. cyclically permuting the sequence n times results in the sequence itself, where "cyclically permuting" can use all possible cyclic permutations? EDIT: If the order can be any divisor of the length of the sequence, why can't the order of 1,1,0,1,1,0 be 2? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jbernazzani: No, this is not about that concept of cyclical permutations. "under cyclic permutation" here only refers to the one permutation $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ that cyclically permutes all the entries in the given order. This is also a frequently used sense of "cyclic permutation".

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, by this permutation: 1,1,0,1,1,0 becomes 0,1,1,0,1,1, becomes 1,0,1,1,0,1 becomes 1,1,0,1,1,0? There appear to be three permutations - is my logic correct? Thanks!

Comment: @jbernazzani: Yes, correct!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! If I were to extend this logic to two-row arrays, do I apply the permutation to the columns?

Comment: @jbernazzani: Yes, I would think so, if I understand correctly the scenario you're thinking of.

Comment: Thanks, the scenario is a colored generalized frobenius partition where the colors are cyclically permuted.

Comment: @jbernazzani: I'm not familiar with that. Generally speaking, if the colours are cyclically permuted, everything related to colours should be cyclically permuted.